# How to get readable toString of java.util.function.Predicate

Tags: java, lambda, guava, tostring, predicate

Let's `import java.util.function.Predicate` and define following predicates:

```
    Predicate<String> a = ...
    Predicate<String> b = ...
```

The `a.and(b).toString()` expression returns `java.util.function.Predicate$$Lambda$3/1667689440@2698dc7`.

Now, let's change import to

```
    import com.google.common.base.Predicate;
    import com.google.common.base.Predicates;
```

and evaluate expression `Predicates.and(a,b).toString()`.

We get `Predicates.and(...,...)`.

In my usecase the original predicates have readable `toString()` (they are either Guava builtin predicates or anonymous classes with overridden `toString()`).

While Guava implements own class `AndPredicate` with overridden `toString()`, Java `Predicate.and()` is implemented just as a lambda. The Guava way is lot more practical for debugging or error messages.

Is there any way to get some useful info from such a Java `Predicate` (drill into lambda or such)? (Questions relates to other functional interfaces as well.)

Thanks!